# When documenting the employees performance

Tags: professionalism, termination, offices

My question is when employer is documenting the employee for evaluations and then they poke at things like shakiness, flushed face, nervousness should that be a just a reason to give them an unsatisfactory evaluation and is it more correct to evaluate them  based off of their productivity then these characteristics?

Answer (score 11):

A performance review is for *performance review*. It's hard to say if shakiness, flushed face and nervousness impact the employees performance. It depends.

If it's *Alice from Accounting*, who turns red like a lobster and is terribly nervous when spoken to privately *in her lunch break*, then **NO**. This has nothing to do with her accounting job.

If it's *Marc from Marketing*, who was a nervous wreck *at the main press conference* where he was to present the new product model? **YES**, that was not his best performance then.

You will have to figure that out for yourself, depending on the job in question.